Why isn't printf printing a float passed by a variable?
Why is the following:
int main(void)
{
    double b = 11/2;
    double a = 2;
    printf("%lf\n", a + b);
    printf("%lf\n", b);
}

printing, respectively, 7.000000 and 5.000000
I tried printing just the value of 5.5, without having it in a variable and then passing it to printf and it worked, but why does this code don't?

Integer division. 11 / 2 --> 5. Try double b = 11 / 2.0; or double b = (double)11 / 2; etc.

Aside: you don't need %lf for double in printf(). The %f is double, unlike in scanf().

@WeatherVane — But since C99, %lf works for double with printf() as well as scanf(), so consistency suggests using %lf for both printing and scanning double values.

"%lf" does not match double in scanf().  It matches double *.

The constants 11 and 2 have type int, so dividing them performs integer division which truncates any fractional part.
Use floating point constants instead so floating point division happens.
double b = 11.0/2.0;

